# Selecionar dia da semana

Tags: android

Estou fazendo uma aplicação no qual o usuário deve selecionar se a ação vai ser repetir em determinado dia da semana, queria fazer algo parecido com o que temos no despertador do Android:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que eu fiz até o momento foi utilizar um `ToggleButton` para cada dia da semana, existe algum componente especifico para esses botões ou eu tenho alguma maneira de customizar o `ToggleButton`?

Comment: Ótima pergunta! Vou preparar um exemplo de Custom View e postá-lo aqui.

Comment: Você pode criar um selector e usá-lo como background do seu ToggleButton